# how to bind Eclipse RCP Table View to other thread data

Tags: multithreading, data-binding, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have just started with Eclipse RCP.
I created Eclipse RCP View with TableViewer and WritableList to get data from other thread.
But I cannot see any changes. I need only to show content of List that other thread is managing.

```
public class View extends ViewPart {
private TableViewer viewer; 
private WritableList input;
```

I also can get error,

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.AssertionFailedException: assertion failed: Getter called outside realm of observable org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.list.WritableList
```

I know what is UI Thread. I just don't know how to write. Please help with example.

UPDATE. Was not solved, because of lack of time, and missing good and focused tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I received this error message also with my code.
Databinding observables (WritableList, WritableValue...) inherit from `ChangeManager`, which provides `ChangeManager#getRealm` and the realm has `Realm#exec`. Within the runnable provided to `exec`, the operation runs in the correct thread.

This line caused the error (*Getter called outside realm of observable*):

```
WritableValue value = getEditor().getWritableValue();
System.out.println(((RcpEditorModel) value.getValue()).getNumber());
```

And this prevented the exception:

```
WritableValue value = getEditor().getWritableValue();
value.getRealm().exec(() -> System.out.println(((RcpEditorModel) value.getValue()).getNumber()));
```

The same will work with `WritableList` since it also inherits from `ChangeManager`.